# Call a controller action of an engine in a multi-engine Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines, doorkeeper

Currently I am working on a multi-engine app with the user authentication(Devise) engine and the core API(with doorkeeper) engine being two of them.

Now when the user authenticates, I need to create an `access_token` for doorkeeper. For this when the user signs in, I need to make another call to the API engine `/oauth/token` to generate the token from inside the `OmniAuthController` of Devise.

So, basically i need to call a different route from within a controller action.

What are the elegant options to do this in Rails?